# SQL using sp_OAGetProperty to get video dimensions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to get the sp_OAGetProperty for some video files I have (1080p; 720p;etc) by querying the attributes in SQL using sp_OAGetProperty.

I do this with no problem for things like "DateCreated" but I'm not sure how to get it to work for Dimensions.

Can anyone give guidance on how to get this to work for Dimensions?   Is there a different attribute name?    It's giving me "" when i run it.

Here's an example I have running for Date Created. (I'm also trying to capture length but it doesn't like that property either.  Not really worried about that.)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnc_GetFileDimensions]

(@FileName VARCHAR (1024))

RETURNS @Results TABLE (
ErrorCode TINYINT DEFAULT (0),
PropName VARCHAR (255),
PropValue SQL_VARIANT
)

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @OLEResult INT
DECLARE @FS INT
DECLARE @FileID INT
DECLARE @Message VARCHAR (8000)
DECLARE @ErrorSource VARCHAR (255)
DECLARE @ErrorDesc VARCHAR (255)
DECLARE @INT INT
DECLARE @VARCHAR VARCHAR (1024)
DECLARE @DATETIME DATETIME
DECLARE @BIGINT BIGINT

-- Create an instance of the file system object
EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @FS OUT
IF @OLEResult <> 0
BEGIN
EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @FS, @ErrorSource OUT, @ErrorDesc OUT

INSERT @Results (ErrorCode, PropName, PropValue)
VALUES (1, @ErrorSource, @ErrorDesc)

RETURN
END

EXEC @OLEResult = sp_OAMethod @FS, 'GetFile', @FileID OUT, @Filename
IF @OLEResult <> 0
BEGIN
EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @FS, @ErrorSource OUT, @ErrorDesc OUT

INSERT @Results (ErrorCode, PropName, PropValue)
VALUES (1, @ErrorSource, @ErrorDesc)

RETURN
END

EXEC @OLEResult = sp_OAGetProperty @FileID, 'Dimensions', @INT OUT
IF @OLEResult <> 0
BEGIN
INSERT @Results (ErrorCode, PropName, PropValue)
VALUES (1, 'Dimensions', '<ERROR RETRIEVING PROPERTY>')
END
ELSE
INSERT @Results (PropName, PropValue)
VALUES ('Dimensions', @INT)

EXEC @OLEResult = sp_OAGetProperty @FileID, 'Duration', @DATETIME OUT
IF @OLEResult <> 0
BEGIN
INSERT @Results (ErrorCode, PropName, PropValue)
VALUES (1, 'Duration', '<ERROR RETRIEVING PROPERTY>')
END
ELSE
INSERT @Results (PropName, PropValue)
VALUES ('Duration', @DATETIME)

EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OADestroy @FileID
EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OADestroy @FS

RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare 
    @filedir nvarchar(300) = 'c:\temp\afolder', --directory contains the file
    @filename nvarchar(300) = 'Video001.avi' --the filename

--property holder
declare @props table
(
i int,
propname nvarchar(100),
propvalue nvarchar(100)
);

--command&object pointers
declare 
    @command nvarchar(500),
    @shellId int, @dirId int, @fileId int;

--shell
exec sp_OACreate 'shell.application', @shellId out;
--set folder of shell and get directory out
select @command = N'NameSpace("'+@filedir+N'")';
exec sp_OAMethod @shellId, @command, @dirId out;
--get fileid
exec sp_OAMethod @dirId, 'ParseName', @fileId out, @filename;

--iteration, lazy..
declare @i int = 0,
    @propname nvarchar(100),
    @propvalue nvarchar(100);

while @i <= 450
begin
    select @propname = null, @propvalue = null;
    
    --property of fileid
    exec sp_OAMethod @dirId, 'GetDetailsOf', @propvalue out, @fileId, @i;

    if nullif(@propvalue, N'') is not null
    begin
        --get property name : GetDetailsOf null
        exec sp_OAMethod @dirId, 'GetDetailsOf', @propname out, null, @i;
    
        insert into @props(i, propname, propvalue)
        values(@i, @propname, @propvalue);
    end

    --next iteration
    select @i = @i + 1;
end

--destroy
exec sp_OADestroy @fileId;
exec sp_OADestroy @dirId;
exec sp_OADestroy @shellId;

select *
from @props;
```